# NSFontPanel: Shadow color -- where art thou?

Tags: nsfontmanager, nsfontpanel

Tinkering with the `NSFontPanel` here.  It would appear that, if you resize the stock panel wide enough, you automagically get the ability to turn shadows on/off, the shadow opacity, blur, offset and direction.  Even works in TextEdit.

Nice.

However, Apple's NSFontPanel implementation only has gray-scale shadows -- **no color**.  This is despite `NSShadow` allowing for color.

**I'd be *really* nice to have colored shadows.**

Two questions:

1) How can one (easily) add a shadow ColorWell to the NSFontPanel?  Assuming the use of the user-provided accessory view for this.  Here's to hoping it can play nicely with the existing NSFontPanel toolbar layout.

2) Barring that, here's a kludge: my app will not use the background color attribute.  Any thoughts on my hijacking that for my shadow color?

-- bp

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps NSUserInterfaceValidations can help?